# Javascript Encrypt Form before sending with AES

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm trying to build a Diary system, with local En/Decryption so that the entries can only be read by the user with the password, which is not stored on the server.
The Crypto should be done with Javascript(CryptoJS), but I have to manipulate the data of a HTML-form, before it's send.
If it's possible, this should be done without JQuery, because of performance and bandwidth.
Bacause I'm relatively new to java script, I don't know, how to manipulate the  data of the form, when the submit button was clicked ? :)

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
```

Comment: as long as your server can handle gobblygook instead of normal post data, then you can just send the blob over and echo it out later un-impeded.

Comment: yes, but i'm new to javasctipt, and wanted to know, how to manipulate the form when the submit butten is clicked :)

Comment: Make your own research on how to capture form data and send it, it's not a unique problem.

Comment: well, you can't use the submit button anymore. at least, not with out totally re-implementing it anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why u think jquery is slow or gives u a large amount of data to send.
But u can transform any jquery code into normal javascript so this should be no problem. I will give some hints in jquery because i dont know all the things in pure js and will not google this for u :)

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent form beeing send
    var allFormDatas = {}; //Object thats stores all form data
    $.each($("#youtform").find("input"),function() { //loop over all inputs in the form
        allFormDatas[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val(); //Gets the value from an form element and puts into "allFormDatas"
    });

    var stringForEncryption = JSON.stringify(allFormDatas); //Now we have one long Json string for encryption
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(stringForEncryption, "Secret Passphrase");
    //Now use $.post here to send post data to your backend.
});

//Encryption should be 
encrypted>decrypt>parseJson>jsObject
```

PS: this is not tested and will not get dropdown and checkbox elements but you get an idea i hope :)

---

EDIT: A smarter solution... thanks to @dandavis:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formString = $( this ).serialize(); // All data in one String.
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(formString, "Secret Passphrase");
  //Now use $.post here to send post data to your backend.
});
```

Comment: if you're gonna use jQuery, just use the https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ command to get the whole form into one string, encrypt the string, and send that encrypted string to the server.

Comment: oh this is smart yhea dont knew this function yet ty